# How to merge two cursor in resultant cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with sqlite where i have fired a query with "IN" operator but its taking to much time to display data. My query is following :

```
String Sql_query = "select id as _id,PARTY_NAME, PARTY_ADD1 as PARTY_ADD1,PARTY_KEY,PARTY_VAT   from  PARTYMAST where PARTY_KEY in(  Select OUTACCD from OUTLETMST   where OUTSMCD = " + salesman_code  + "  and  Party_name  like '" + etsearch.getText() + "%')";
```

Now to reducing time to get data i have made two cursors like below :

```
String Sql = "select   id as _id,PARTY_NAME, PARTY_ADD1 as PARTY_ADD1,PARTY_KEY,PARTY_VAT from  PARTYMAST";

String Sql2 = "Select OUTACCD from OUTLETMST   where OUTSMCD = " + salesman_code  + "  and  Party_name  like '" + etsearch.getText() + "%')";


Cursor c1 = dbhelper.showdata(this,Sql);

Cursor c2 = dbhelper.showdata(this,Sql2);
```

Now i want to merge this two cursors c1 and c1 in one cursor like `c1 + c2 = main_cursor`

I have merged both cursor like following code :

```
MergeCursor merge_cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] {
                c1, c2});
```

But it not worked in merge_cursor i getting only data of first cursor (c1).
Is it possible ? Please guide if anybody face this type of proble

Any other way to write this query ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use join in your sql query.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "merge"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Join or Union for it.

Like for an example :-

```
sql = sql1;
sql += " UNION "
sql += sql2;
```